# Create a Form loaded with data from excel file

Tags: python, forms

I would like to build a form with predefined data from an excel file that is loaded into the form as well as having some additional columns within the form that can be editable?

Please can someone advise me how I could do this on Python?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your-excel.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

If you want to add columns:

```
Test = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4']
df['Test'] = Test
df
```

Comment: Hello, What I am trying to do is feed in the data from an excel file to appear in a new window dialogue:

I have developed the below code but all the data is put together. 

how I can separate the data for each column?

import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *

df= pd.read_excel('Master Data.xlsx') 
root = Tk ()
root.title('Employee Opinion Survey Ordering')
root.geometry("500x800")

list = ''
for c in df.iterrows():
    list = f'{list + str("t".join(c[1].values.astype("str")))}​​​​​ \n'
    
label_a = Label(root, text=list)

label_a.pack(pady=20)

root,mainloop()